# pdnsd with IPv6 host - "Could not discover udp destination address"

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

I'm starting to play around with IPv6 and am trying to work within the constraints of an existing platform and set of services.  Right now I'm trying to get DNS working over IPv6 using pdnsd.

From my client machine, I can ping6 and ssh (using the IPv6 address) to the server running pdnsd (and vice versa).  When I do a host lookup from the client machine that causes a query to my server running pdnsd, with "tcpdump ip6" I can see that the DNS query is going out, looking for a AAAA record.  With debugging turned on, I see the following logged by pdnsd on the server every time a query is made:

> pdnsd[4032]: Could not discover udp destination address

Lookups of the same host via pdnsd locally from the server running pdnsd work fine.  Any ideas?   Anybody else using pdnsd with IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help somebody else in the future.

I was using the Debian distro version of pdnsd which is apparently compiled with "source address discovery" enabled.  I obtained the source and configured it with:

./configure **--disable-src-addr-disc** --enable-ipv6 --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc

After deploying this version, I am able to resolve from the remote machine.

I admit I don't really understand what the trade-offs are of including/not including the source address discover option, other than it doesn't work for me with the option enabled.

For my short term experimentation, just getting it working is good enough though.  :)